# Spread array or range to arguments of SWITCH

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I switch using an array or a range of values in google sheets? In other words, how can I use the range of values in B2:B to work as the "Switch" Parameters in the formula below?

The 1st formula used in the table below generates the desired result in column C

```
1. arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"",SWITCH(trim(A2:A),"A","B","C","D"),""))
```

But the 2nd formula I use evaluates as #N/A

```
2.  arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"",SWITCH(trim(A2:A),JOIN(",",FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>""))),""))
```

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Values | Replacement | Desired (using formula 1) |
| 2 | A | "A","B" | B |
| 3 | C | "C","D" | D |

**What I tried - replacing using switch**

Both `textjoin(",",TRUE,B2:B)` and `JOIN(",",FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>""))` result in `"A","B","C","D"` so I figured that replacing those values in formula 1 above as in the 2nd formula would work buy it didn't instead evaluating to #N/A

Can I use `SWITCH` with a range that is generated or is there some other way to achieve using the joining the values in column B to be used to replace values in column C?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B3, "\b"&A2:A3&"\b", )))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A6, SPLIT(B2, "|"), 2, ), 
                 VLOOKUP(A2:A6, SPLIT(B3, "|"), 2, )), A2:A6))
```

[image]

Comment: Need to work in context of array. For example, if A4=C --> C4=D. Something like: INDEX(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B, "\b"&A2:A&"\b", )))

Comment: @MMsmithH if you change A2 to B in your sheet, do you expect to get A? or value in A column is always the first item in B column and you want to get always only the 2nd item of B column?

Comment: @MMsmithH answer updated

Answer (score 1):

No. Currently, It's not possible to unpack/unzip/spread a array/range to arguments of a function.

Workaround in this specific case would be to use regex:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(B2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(B2:B)),"["&A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A))&",""]",))
```

This creates a regex like `[A",]`, where

- `[]` is a character class
- `A",` is literal `A`,`"` and `,`

If it matches, it gets replaced with nothing.